# How can I stop slider jssor action on drag start event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jssor slider, and in one of the slide I've put a calendar with fullCalendar.
My problem comes when I drag an calendar event to move it to another date, because in addition to moving the event, the slider acts and is changed to another slider window.
Can I stop the action of the slider when I detect the drag start event?
Any other way to do it?

Code HTML (jssor slider + FullCalendar):

```
<div id="slider1_container" class="green-background">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
        <div id="first-slide" class="green-background">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1" style="padding-right: 1em;">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="second-slide" class="green-background"></div>
        <div id="third-slide" class="green-background"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code to jssor slider:

```
var options = { $AutoPlay: false };
jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
```

JS code to fullCalendar:

```
var hoy = new Date();
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    contentHeight: 380,
    header:false,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    events: [
        {id:2 , title: 'New event1', start:  '2017-02-15'}
    ],
    editable: true,
    defaultDate: hoy,
    selectable: true,
    eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
        // Code to stop slide
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Pablo, Welcome to Stackoverflow, Add the code you are trying and then ask for Help. There is no way someone can help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry! It is my first question and I dont know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute 'data-nodrag' to prevent dragging on an element.

```
<div data-nodrag="true" ...>
```

**Edit**

```
<div class="col-md-11">
    <div data-nodrag="true" id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jssor slider?

Comment: Yes! I just downloaded the latest version, but it does not work.

Comment: please leave an url of your slider.

Comment: Hi! The reference to my file jssor.js was broken and it took the previous version, not the latest. It works now!! Thanks you so much!

Comment: Hi! If I put "data-nodrag = true" on img, button... element type it works, but on a "div" it does not work.

Comment: It would appreciated if I can have your page url.

Comment: D'ont worry! I accept this answer as correct. I have put "data-nodrag = true" on fullcalendar event instead of 'div', and it works perfectly! Again, thanks you so much!